# How to create a Backgammon board in ASP.NET with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created a backgammon game in c++ that is played in console. Now I want to update it to be played online. At the moment both players would be playing from the same computer, so I don't need to worry about connections and messages.

In my C++ version the board is a 2D array, and i was thinking of representing it with a 'gridview' and making the 'columns' be 'buttonfields' so that when you press them I could check the logic and if valid make the movements.

I have the feeling there has to be better ways of doing this.

any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably best off making the graphical part of your game using client-side graphics. I have used [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) in the past.

And in order to tell the server what is going on on the board use a [WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx).

To do this you'll need to brush up on [JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off creating an image that represents the board, and drawing this to a surface in your application, and then defining various clickable "hotspots".  You'll run into limitations and frustrations if you try to turn controls into a board game and you might not be that satisfied with the final results.

Comment: +1 This method is probably going to be easier to do for someone who doesn't have any existing client-side scripting knowledge.

Comment: I will look into client-side graphics and if it gets too crazy I will go through with this option.